# How to use structure from VB6 using COM interop?

Tags: c#-4.0, vb6, com-interop

Here is scenario:

I have a VB6 project. It contains a method which receives parameter of type variant by ref.

```
Function GetFilledInfo(data As Variant)
```

This method fills the received parameter with a structure. This structure is defined in my VB6 project as follows.

```
Public Type DATASTRUCTMAIN
   structChild As DATASTRUCTCHILD
End Type

Public Type DATASTRUCTCHILD
   m_bComputeRanges As Long
End Type
```

I have a C# program which calls this method by referring the ActiveX dll generated by VB6 project.

I want to declare structure that is defined in VB6 inside my C# program and want to get it filled by using VB6 method.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help noticing that you are only passing a Long (unless you have truncated those structure definitions for brevity). In that case, just change the VB6 so that it exposes a function that returns a Long!

If you have a real structure...

Move the structure definition to a public class in your VB6 project. Then the structure definition will become publicly available through COM for any clients who reference your VB6 project.

*Hopefully* you will be able to use it in your C# project and you will be able to declare instances of the structure. You do have a reference to the VB6 component in the Project References in your C# project, right? Not too familiar with .Net COM interop, so not sure about this.

If you have any problems declaring instances of the structure in your C# project, you could change the VB6 structure into a class? [Apparently structures can be problematic in COM interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489368/returning-multiple-results-udt-from-an-interop-call-vb6-vb-net)